# Coldfusion Solr Search - equivalent to LIKE %string% in SQL

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How to do a SOLR search with the same logic of the following SQL search query?

```
SELECT * FROM user where email LIKE '%ben%'"
```

I tried the following,

```
<cfscript>
    mysearch = new com.adobe.coldfusion.search();
    searchResult = mysearch.search(collection="mycollection", criteria='ben*'); 
</cfscript>
```

1. `criteria='ben*'` matched 'raw_*ben*@yahoo.com' and '*ben*@yahoo.com' but didn't return string 'ro**ben** ro**ben**'.
2. `criteria='ben~'` matched 'raw_*ben*@yahoo.com' and '*ben*@yahoo.com' but didn't return string 'ro**ben** ro**ben**'.

Same goes for all fuzzy search, wild search attempts.

Comment: whats the fieldType for the search field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change the fieldType for your field which can generate tokens using solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory
With the help of which you can generate the tokes e.g. abhijit would generate abh, abhi, abhij, abhiji, abhijit and hence would match all these combination for your query.

with the second EdgeNGramFilterFactory it will generate the tokens
jit, ijit, hijit, bhijit, abhijit, iji, hiji, bhiji etc. so on...

try with below field type

```
<fieldType name="text_reference" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
       <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: my problem is that the 'ben' in 'ro**ben**' which is in the middle of a string is not added to list of key words. is there any way?

Comment: what are the possible values for attribute side?

Comment: front and back are the possible values

Comment: when I put "**raw_ben**" as keyword to search, no results are found

Comment: Can you check the same in web interface i.e. analysis page ...http://localhost/solr/CORE_NAME/admin/analysis.jsp.... specify CORE_NAME if you have created any other wise http://localhost/solr/admin/analysis.jsp